# ffprobe get MP3 file encoder settings

Tags: ffprobe

When I open a MP3 file in MediaInfo it shows me the encoder settings used to encode. For example:

```
Encoding settings                        : -m s -V 0 -q 0 -lowpass 20 --vbr-new -b 192
```

Any way to get that info using ffprobe? By default it lists the encoder library (LAME3.90, etc), but doesn't show the encoder settings. I've tried the following command but still no luck:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -stats -i song.mp3
```

EDIT: After further research there is a LAME/Xing tag in the file which has this information.

Comment: Have you tried `ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams input.mp4`?

Comment: Just tried, but still doesn't show it.

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: @Gyan, not able to share the file but any file encoded with LAME will have it. There will be a LAME tag which stores this info.